# C# Linq Query group by check if result is null

Tags: c#, linq

If I have a class like this

```
public class Test
{
   public string Id {get; set;}
   public string Name {get; set;}
   public int Value {get; set;}
}
```

and then:

```
List<Test> values = new List<Test>(); // this contains let's say 10 items
```

and I do like this:

```
var grouped = values.Where(x=>x.Value > 10).GroupBy(x=>x.Name);
```

My question is how can I check if `grouped == null`? Or how can I check that there are no groupings that matches that criteria?

I am asking because if I do like this:

```
if (grouped == null) // this is false although the linq yielded no results
{

}
```

Comment: You need to call .ToList() after the GroupBy or some other function to cause the Linq query to be evaluated. Then you can check if the list is empty.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use method `Any()`:

```
var anyItems = grouped.Any();
```

You do not need to check for null, because grouping would return an empty collection instead of null

Answer (score 5):

You could check if there is no groups, like below:

```
var anyGroups = grouped.Any();
```

If there is at least one group, the extension method called `Any` will return `true`. Otherwise it will return `false`.

According to [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb534501%28v=vs.100%29.aspx), this is the signature of the method `GroupBy`:

```
public static IEnumerable<IGrouping<TKey, TSource>> GroupBy<TSource, TKey>(
    this IEnumerable<TSource> source,
    Func<TSource, TKey> keySelector)
```

It is clear from the above that this method returns a sequence of items that implement the `IGrouping` interface. (`IGrouping` Represents a collection of objects that have a common key). An easy way to find out if a sequence contains elements, is using the enumerable's extension method called `Any`.

Furthermore this is a `O(1)` operation -using the `Any` method and not passing any predicate in it. While using the enumerable's extension method called `Count`, in some cases is an `O(n)` operation.

Comment: That was easy! Thanks! :)

Answer (score 2):

`GroupBy` never returns `null`. When there are no records in the result, you would get an empty `IEnumerable<IGrouping<TKey,TSource>>` object.

In your case `GroupBy` is unnecessary: you can replace it with

```
var anyGreaterThanTen = values.Any(x=>x.Value > 10);
```

Answer (score 0):

Using `Any()` is good enough, but it not the most optimal solution.

You obviously need to iterate through the result after you have found that there are some results, but calling `Any()` before iterating over the result, causes the query to run two times. This is not a big deal for a simple example like you have here, but if it was a query over a database (LINQ to SQL or Entity Framework), then you had two database hits. Once to check that if there are any results, and next to fetch the results.

To avoid this, you can write:

```
bool hasResult = false;
// iterating over the result, and performing your task
foreach(var group in grouped)
{
    hasResult = true;

    // process data
    // ...
}

if(!hasResult)
{
    // ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I have the same problem when checking whether result is null. So, I've debugged it.
I've found that when a result has no group, it sometimes has no element or 1 element but this element is null. Therefore, to check where the result is not null, we should combine 2 conditions like below:

```
if(grouped.Count() > 0 && grouped.ElementAt(0) != null)
    {
       //TODO:....enter code here
    }
```